# How not to close the dialog box when refreshed?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, page-refresh

I am trying to create a dialog box.

Here is the snippet of the dialog box:

```
        $("#dialog-form").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height:'auto',
            maxWidth: 500,
            width:'auto',
            fluid: true,
            modal: true,
            buttons:{
                "Close":function(){
                    $(this).dialog("close")
                }
            }
        });
```

Is it possible not to close the dialog box when refreshed? and how to do so?

Comment: When they refresh the page?

Comment: Setting a coockie may be a solution, depending on what you'd like to achieve ...

Comment: Yeah, you can use cookies to save state. You need to do this server-side though, you can't do it with pure js. Also, it's likely to annoy the hell out of the end-users.

Comment: You can set a cookie via JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, could you also provide a sample code for this?